# naive bayesian spam filter question

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, naivebayes, spam-prevention

I am planning to implement spam filter using Naive Bayesian classification model.

Online I see a lot of info on Naive Bayesian classification, but the problem is its a lot of mathematical stuff, than clearly stating how its done. **And the problem is I am more of a programmer than a mathematician** (yes I had learnt Probability and Bayesian theorem back in school, but out of touch for a long long time, and I don't have luxury of learning it now (Have nearly 3 weeks to come-up with a working prototype)).

So if someone can explain or point me to location where its explained for programmers than a mathematician, it would be a great help.

PS: By the way I have to implement it in C, if you want to know. :(

Regards,
Microkernel

Comment: suck it up and learn the math. if you don't you never have a hope in improving yourself, you will always merely be a pawn in a larger game.

Comment: @gmatt: Yes I agree with you. But its not that I am not good @ math or I hate math. Incidentally my favourite subject @school used to be math. But now I don't have time to relearn and implement (consider, I have atmost 3 weeks to do this, to be implemented in C, and this is a project for some weekend class, and apart from this I have a full time job(which needless to say sucking away vitality from me)). 

But I still strongly agree with you and I really want to learn. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book [Programming Collective Intelligence](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529321) has chapter that covers this and other methods.  The chapter (#6) can be understood without reference to previous chapters, is written clearly, and discusses only the minimal mathematics necessary to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this [website](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184406064). It's got some source code.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend [Andrew Moore's tutorials](http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/) and I think you should start with [this one](http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/prob18.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at [POPFile](http://sourceforge.net/projects/popfile/), an open source spam filter engine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at dspam?

http://dspam.irontec.com/faq.shtml#1.0

http://www.nuclearelephant.com/